# How to solve for $\theta$ in the equation $\sin(2\theta) = \sin(\theta)$ using complex numbers?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, roots

I know how to solve for $\theta$ using the general solution method, by transposing $\sin(\theta)$ to the other side and applying the identity $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ to get the equation $\sin(\theta)(2\cos(\theta) - 1) = 0$ and then taking the general solution for $\sin(\theta) = 0$ and $2\cos(\theta) - 1 = 0$.

But I want to know how to use complex numbers to solve this question and get the same answers. I tried using Euler's formula and writing both $\sin(\theta)$ and $\sin(2\theta)$ as $(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})/2i$ and $(e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta})/2i$ respectively and I even got an equation of the form $y^4 - y^3 + y - 1 = 0$, where $y = e^{i\theta}$. However, solving that only yielded one of the principle solutions i.e $\theta = \pi$, I should also get $\theta = \pi/3$, but I haven't been able to get it.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Formatting note: use \ before trig functions so that they render nicely.

Comment: @Whyareyoureadingmyname ok, I will edit it, thanks!

Comment: Solving $y^4 - y^3 + y - 1 = 0$ yields two results: $y = \pm 1$, so without further inspection there's at least $2$ solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you tried to solve$$y+\frac1y=y^2+\frac1{y^2}.$$This is indeed equivalent to$$y^4-y^3+y-1=0.$$But\begin{align}y^4-y^3+y-1=0&\iff(y-1)(y^3+1)=0\\&\iff y=1(=e^0)\vee y=-1\left(=e^{\pi i}\right)\vee y=e^{i\pi/3}\vee y=e^{5\pi i/3}.\end{align}And so, yes, you do get the solutions $0$, $\pi$, $\frac\pi3$, and $\frac{5\pi}3$. Actually the whole set of solutions of the equation $\sin(\theta)=\sin(2\theta)$ is$$\pi\Bbb Z\cup\left\{\frac\pi3+2n\pi\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb Z\right\}\cup\left\{\frac{5\pi}3+2n\pi\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb Z\right\}.$$

Comment: I understand how you got $y=1$ and $y=−1$, but how did you get $y=e^{(iπ)/3}$ and $y=e^{(5πi)/3}$? I just get the $y^3+1=(y+1)(y^2−y+1)=0$ and on solving $y^2−y+1=0$, I get $y=(1+\sqrt{3}i)/2$ and $y=(1−\sqrt{3}i)/2$. Could you please elaborate on this for me?

Comment: Sure:\begin{align}y^3+1=0&\iff y^3=-1\\&\iff y^3=e^{\pi i/2}\\&\iff y=e^{\pi i/6}\vee y=e^{3\pi i/6}\vee y=e^{5\pi i/6}\\&\iff y=e^{\pi i/6}\vee y=-1\vee y=e^{5\pi i/6}.\end{align}

Comment: But isn't $e^{(iπ)/2} = i$? I didn't understand how -1 became $e^{(iπ)/2}$ above.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Here it goes:\begin{align}y^3+1=0&\iff y^3=-1\\&\iff y^3=e^{\pi i}\\&\iff y=e^{\pi i/3}\vee y=e^{3\pi i/3}\vee y=e^{5\pi i/3}\\&\iff y=e^{\pi i/3}\vee y=-1\vee y=e^{5\pi i/3}.\end{align}

Comment: Ok, so I now understand how you got $y=e^{(πi)/3}$, but how did you get $y=e^{(3πi)/3}$ and $y=e^{(5πi)/3}$?

Comment: From the fact that the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of $\exp(i\theta)$ are$$\exp\left(\frac{i\theta}n\right),\exp\left(\frac{i\theta+2i\pi}n\right),\exp\left(\frac{i\theta+4i\pi}n\right),\ldots,\exp\left(\frac{i\theta+2(n-1)i\pi}n\right)$$

Comment: Ah yes, I completely forgot about that. Ok now I understand everything, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.